# Double integrals evaluation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to calculate the value of these integrals:

$$\int\int_{(0,e)\times(0,+\infty)}\frac{x\log x}{1+(xy)^2}dxdy,$$
$$\int\int_{(0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)}\frac{x \arctan x}{(1+x^2)(x^2+y^2)}dxdy.$$

I've tried using Tonelli's theorem, but I'm not able to calculate the value of the expressions that I get.

In addition, I would appreciate it if you could recommend me a book with solved problems on multivariable integration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, you may integrate $y$ first to get
$$
I_1 = \int_0^{e}\frac{\pi  \log (x)}{2}dx
$$
and 
$$
I_2=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\pi \tan ^{-1}(x)}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)}dx.
$$
Both of these integrals are easily computed via
$$
\int \log(x) dx = x(\log(x)-1) + C
$$
and
$$
\int \frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+1}  = \frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}(x)^2 + C
$$
to give
$$
I_1=0
$$
and
$$
I_2 = \frac{\pi ^3}{16}.
$$